# Developing a Windows driver without using Microsoft's compiler

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

My team has a C-language codebase that is used in several embedded systems of varying platforms.  We have a group of people that are trying to port part of this codebase into a Windows driver.  However, certain aspects of Microsoft's compiler don't jive with our existing code base (C99 features, among other things).  We try to keep a common codebase between products and avoid creating forks for certain platforms, but the number of Windows-specific workarounds and `#ifdefs` is getting messy.

Is there a way to build a Windows driver using a compiler other than Microsoft's?  Our codebase compiles fine under `gcc` and GreenHills, and we should be able to use the Intel C compiler on it as well (it's been a while since we've tried, but it should still work).  Being able to use a different compiler would help keep our code cleaner, plus it would save us time and effort.  All of the documentation that we have been able to locate refers to using either Visual Studio or the Windows DDK.

If the Microsoft compiler or DDK is indeed required, would it be possible to build the bulk of our code as a static library using another compiler and then use the Windows DDK to create a wrapper around that library?

Comment: What version of the compiler are you using now?

Comment: We're using whatever is packaged with the current Windows DDK.  The builds are actually done on an automated build server so I don't have a copy of it in front of me to get the exact version number.

Comment: From a build window: just type cl.exe without any command line arguments.  Version 16.x is the latest version corresponding to Visual Studio 2010.  If the DDK/WDK are an older version, you could likely install Visual C++ express and then fix up your DDK build environment to use that compiler instead.

Comment: But the question is, can we use a non-Microsoft compiler (that includes Visual Studio as well as the compiler that comes with the DDK)?

Comment: My point was that the newer compiler may have the C99 support you desire.  Whereas, the one shipping with the DDK was likely the version that shipped with that version of the OS. C99 support is incrementally added in each release.  If you can't upgrade, go try the Intel compiler. It will either work or it won't.  I heard the command line args for Intel's compiler is similar such that it's a drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend such thing even if you succeed to compile. You can never know the side effects. The only compiler to be used is the one in WDK (it's incorporated into VS2012). Even the MS non-WDK compiler (any VS version prior to VS2012) not suitable here.

The same answer goes for building library with other compiler and linking it with MS one. It's not a question of "how to fool the OS" but rather "how to do the right thing". I suppose you can have a limited portion of code compiled with other compiler (e.g. compile code in C99 that is not supported by MS) but it's risky.